# Hidden state output from jags model in R

Tags: r, bayesian, jags, state-space, r2jags

Does the "jags" function of R2jags give estimated states output when estimating a state space model?

Or is it to be derived manually using estimated mean/medians of parameter values.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Further to @Community's point, we would at least need the model code, but a full minimal working example would be preferable.